# How to make a graph in Google Data Studio showing specific url parameters that were queried in my site?

Tags: query-string, reporting, regex, google-data-studio

I have a search page on a hotel property website that can have up to 12 parameters in the url.  Note that sometimes it may have none of these parameters.     The parameters are all for optional facilities that the hotel could provide.   If the parameter is present it's value is always 'Yes'.

What I want to do is simply create a visual report such as a bar chart within Data Studio that shows a count of page views for each of these 12 parameters.

To do this I started making custom dimensions using the following REGEX.  Each dimension looks for a specific url parameter.  In this case 'offers'.   To clarify, there are 3 possible scenarios here.  A page may not have the url or it may have it with either 'Yes' or 'No' as a value.

REGEXP_MATCH(Page, '(?i)\boffers=yes\b' )

I know that this is definitely a valid REGEX expression that can detect the url parameter "offers=yes", and it can do this without case sensitivity.

[image: The dimension using REGEX being created]

However even creating a simple table with dimensions using the exact REGEX above and a third column using the 'Page' dimension never seems to show a 'true' result in my table.

[image: Sample table testing for matching url parameters]

Ultimately I want to visualise this into a bar graph that shows columns for the number of references to each url parameter I am tracking, irrelevant of the page the parameter was part of.  Here is a mockup of this *ideal* end result...

[image: Mockup of ideal desired results]

Comment: share your data source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Constructing a Data Studio Report with Regex

1. Create a report and click edit next to your data source
2. Select "Add Field"

[image]

### Creating Custom Regex Field

> In Data Studio escaping is weird. You have to use `\\/` instead of `\/` to escape a `/`.

The following regex will match urls with a query string in your example:

```
REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, '.*/\\?swimmingpool=yes$' )
```

[image]

3. Add your regex and then select **Update** > **Done**
4. Next, create a chart and add dimensions with the field you just created

[image]

In my example, you can now see that `/?x=yes` returns true.

---

If you want to use a bar chart we can do that too by creating a **Chart Field**:

[image]

Next add your conditions:

[image: ``]

and Viola!

[image]

These probably aren't exactly what you're looking for, but you can use these examples to create your own custom reports.

Edit: If you want to filter out anything that *does not* include your query parameters:

[image: add filter to data studio report]

Now select our "has query string" metric. This is an example of why creating custom dimensions and metrics is useful. See, we created both a dimension and metric for things with query strings. The metric, which is just a variable, that we named `has query string` we gave the value `Has Query String = True`. It's a boolean, meaning it's value is either True or False, 0 or 1. In our regex for the dimension we created we are matching urls that have our query string. We're using the metric to help us be *more specific*.

[image]

Now we have only the urls that match, nothing more.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for helping Mike.  What I want is a graph with the 20 or so possible url parameters we have that are for optional extras in the hotels.  So I need to manually define these in the regex I believe, otherwise we may get all sorts of things appearing.     It may be that my regex shown in the question is fine.    The main issue I have is that I'm just not sure how to construct the report I want to see.   I simply want page views on the vertical by the unique url param on the horizontal.

Comment: @AdamJones Hopefully you find this example helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this @Mike Ciffone.  I get stuck however adding the metric.   Adding it with the "Has Query String = true" doesn't work as "has query String" isn't found as a metric.  I have already created it as a "dimension" but not a metric.  Can you clarify ?

Comment: @AdamJones Not sure I understand what you mean. Refer to my screenshot, it must be in both places.

Comment: Ok understood. One other question.  You use the dimension 'Landing page'.  In Data Studio, does that refer to the page a user first hits when accessing a site ?     As I don't want that, I want the url irrelevant if it was the first thing they saw when landing on the site or not.

Comment: You could use any dimension that captures a url that you like. Landing page would mean the first page a user landed on. I just used that as an example.

Comment: Ok clear. What I dont understand is how adding these custom metrics/dimensions filter out page hits that don't include the url params I'm looking for.   That doesn't seem to happen from my testing.   Is it meant to do that ?

Comment: @AdamJones We're creating the custom dimensions and metrics _to be_ the filter. What you want to say is "Only show me urls that have these properties". I've just updated my answer. Hopefully now this satisfies your question.

Comment: @AdamJones For the record, I provided you with a step by step guide to creating a report that does exactly what you asked for before the bounty expired.

Comment: Hi Mike.  Sorry to go on about this but I still don't have even the most simple of demonstrations working for this problem.   I've updated my question to highlight this.  You can see that I'm using a table with a dimension of a regex which I'm sure is valid, searching on the 'Page' dimension for url parameter matches.  Yet there is never a 'true' result, even though the page column in the returned table shows that there definitely is a match for the url param within the 'Page' dimension's value.   This is highlighted by the tool tip in my screenshot which shows an 'offers=Yes' value.

Comment: @AdamJones I am not here to do your work for you. I am here to show you how to accomplish the task and then leave it to you to figure it out for yourself. I could have flagged this weeks ago as off topic as at this point it's specific to your site. Figure it out.

Comment: Charming guy Mike

Comment: My apologies, that was uncalled for...it was late and I was really stressed over something. Let me take a look.

Comment: @AdamJones I don't know why that is not working did you have the chart field set properly?